# Preprocessing and feature engineering using AWS Step Function workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I am trying to implement a machine learning workflow using Step Functions in AWS. My code is in a Jupyter notebook instance. The preprocessing and feature engineering part of the workflow is code in separate Python program which I am calling which I am accessing in my ProcessingStep step definition.

The preprocessing step is supposed to do some data type conversion, split the raw data into training and test files and save these files in the defined s3 bucket folder. When I execute the workflow, the preprocessing steps with the follow code given below runs successfully however, it is not creating and saving the training and test files in the defined s3 folder path.

Any inputs why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

```
%%writefile preprocessing.py

import argparse
import os
import warnings

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder, LabelBinarizer, KBinsDiscretizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer

from sklearn.exceptions import DataConversionWarning

warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", category=DataConversionWarning)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--train-test-split-ratio", type=float, default=0.3)
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    print("Received arguments {}".format(args))

    input_data_path = os.path.join("/opt/ml/processing/input", "raw-data.csv")
    
    print("Reading input data from {}".format(input_data_path))
    df = pd.read_csv(input_data_path)
    
    # Handle null values
    df['Gender'][df['Gender'].isnull()]='Male'
    df['Married'][df['Married'].isnull()]='Yes'
    df['LoanAmount'][df['LoanAmount'].isnull()]= df['LoanAmount'].mean()
    df['Loan_Amount_Term'][df['Loan_Amount_Term'].isnull()]='360'
    df['Loan_Amount_Term'][df['Loan_Amount_Term'].isnull()]='360'
    df['Loan_Amount_Term'][df['Loan_Amount_Term'].isnull()]='360'
    df['Loan_Amount_Term'][df['Loan_Amount_Term'].isnull()]='360'
    df['Self_Employed'][df['Self_Employed'].isnull()]='No'
    df['Credit_History'][df['Credit_History'].isnull()]='1'
    df['Dependents'][df['Dependents'].isnull()]='0'
    df.loc[df.Dependents=='3+','Dependents']= 4

    # Convert data types to numeric
    df.loc[df.Loan_Status=='N','Loan_Status']= 0
    df.loc[df.Loan_Status=='Y','Loan_Status']=1

    df.loc[df.Gender=='Male','Gender']= 0
    df.loc[df.Gender=='Female','Gender']=1

    df.loc[df.Married=='No','Married']= 0
    df.loc[df.Married=='Yes','Married']=1

    df.loc[df.Education=='Graduate','Education']= 0
    df.loc[df.Education=='Not Graduate','Education']=1

    df.loc[df.Self_Employed=='No','Self_Employed']= 0
    df.loc[df.Self_Employed=='Yes','Self_Employed']=1

    #property_area = pd.get_dummies(df['Property_Area'],drop_first=True)
    #df = pd.concat([df,property_area],axis=1)

    df['Married']          = df['Married'].astype(str).astype(int)
    df['Dependents']       = df['Dependents'].astype(str).astype(int)
    df['Education']        = df['Education'].astype(str).astype(int)
    df['Self_Employed']    = df['Self_Employed'].astype(str).astype(int)
    df['Loan_Amount_Term'] = df['Loan_Amount_Term'].astype(str).astype(float)
    df['Credit_History']   = df['Credit_History'].astype(str).astype(float)
    df['Loan_Status']      = df['Loan_Status'].astype(str).astype(int)
    #df['Semiurban']        = df['Semiurban'].astype(str).astype(int)
    #df['Urban']            = df['Urban'].astype(str).astype(int)
    df = df.drop('Loan_ID', 1)
    
    split_ratio = args.train_test_split_ratio
    print("Splitting data into train and test sets with ratio {}".format(split_ratio))
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        df.drop("Loan_Status", axis=1), df["Loan_Status"], test_size=split_ratio, random_state=0)
    
    print("Running preprocessing and feature engineering transformations")
    train_features = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(X_train)
    test_features = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(X_train)
    
    print("Train data shape after preprocessing: {}".format(train_features.shape))
    print("Test data shape after preprocessing: {}".format(test_features.shape))
    
    train_features_output_path = os.path.join("/opt/ml/processing/train", "train_features.csv")
    train_labels_output_path = os.path.join("/opt/ml/processing/train", "train_labels.csv")

    test_features_output_path = os.path.join("/opt/ml/processing/test", "test_features.csv")
    test_labels_output_path = os.path.join("/opt/ml/processing/test", "test_labels.csv")

    print("Saving training features to {}".format(train_features_output_path))
    pd.DataFrame(train_features).to_csv(train_features_output_path, header=False, index=False)

    print("Saving test features to {}".format(test_features_output_path))
    pd.DataFrame(test_features).to_csv(test_features_output_path, header=False, index=False)

    print("Saving training labels to {}".format(train_labels_output_path))
    y_train.to_csv(train_labels_output_path, header=False, index=False)

    print("Saving test labels to {}".format(test_labels_output_path))
    y_test.to_csv(test_labels_output_path, header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is an external python script try leveraging - [AWS SDK Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html)

**Example for a JSON File**

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
your_bucketname = 'xyz_bucket'
bucket = s3.Bucket(your_bucketname)

## PUT
s3object = s3.Object(your_bucketname, 'abc.json')
s3object.put(
                Body=(bytes(json.dumps(Analytics).encode('UTF-8')))
            )
```